# How is attribute a String value from a message like on here?

Tags: java, jsp

I am new in jsp domain and I don't know how to attribute a String value from a message because  it give me error

```
<%String mesg=%>
<fmt:message key="msg_valid" bundle="${message}" />
<%;%>
```

The error is this:

> Syntax error on token "=", ; expected

Answer (score 0):

As nicely stated in one of the post by Aniket Kulkarni:

> JSTL variables are actually attributes, and by default are scoped at
>   the page context level. As a result, if you need to access a JSTL
>   variable value in a scriptlet, you can do so by calling the
>   getAttribute() method on the appropriately scoped object (usually
>   pageContext and request)

You can try this:

```
<%
String mesg= (String)pageContext.getAttribute("message");
out.println(resp);
%>
```